# How do I fade in the next image in the list using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a list of images. I would like to fade in the next image after the previous image has faded out. I think it should be fairly simple..

```
<ul class="nav fading">
  <li><?= anchor("#","Supported by",array("class" => "footer-heading disabled")) ?></li>
  <li><?= img("assets/img/1.png") ?></li>
  <li><?= img("assets/img/2.png") ?></li>
</ul>
```

My code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fading img").hide(); //hide everything 
    $(".fading img:first").fadeIn(4000);
    $(".fading img:first").fadeOut(4000,function(){
        $(this).parent().next().fadeIn(4000);
    });
});
```

I've attempted to fade the same image in again, after it has been faded out and that works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".fading img").hide(); //hide everything 
        $(".fading img:first").fadeIn(4000);
        $(".fading img:first").fadeOut(4000,function(){
            $(this).fadeIn(4000);
        });
    });
```

The problem arises when I try to fade in the next image in the list.

Comment: Lots of duplicate answers here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find an `<img>` from the other, you'll have to traverse back down a "*generation*" with `.find()` or `.children()`, having gone up with `.parent()`:

```
$(this)             // the current, `:first` <img>
    .parent()       // to its parent <li> (2nd under the <ul>)
    .next()         // to the last <li>
    .find('img')    // to the <img> under the last <li>
    .fadeIn(4000);
```

Otherwise, the line was finding and attempting to `.fadeIn()` the `<li>` instead, which won't affect the `<img>` under it.

```
$(this).parent().next().fadeIn(4000);
```

Comment: Care to share what you think is wrong? Drive-by voting doesn't really help me try to correct it.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following

Replace this

```
$(this).parent().next().fadeIn(4000);
```

With this

```
$(this).parent().next().find('img').fadeIn(4000);
```